# Google Pay by Stripe causing issue

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, applepay, google-pay

I am  using a stripe provider G-Pay button

`PlatformPayButton( type: PlatformButtonType.donate, borderRadius: 12, onPressed: () async { await StripePaymentHandle().stripeMakeGooglePayment(context); } ),`
When am moving to that  specific  screen  where  button is  this error occured,

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: GoogleCertificatesRslt: not allowed: pkg=com.example.packagename, sha256=[my laptop sha-256 key], atk=false, ver=240213038.true (go/gsrlt)
```

```
W/MobStoreFlagStore(29377): java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.SecurityException: GoogleCertificatesRslt: not allowed: pkg=com.example.packagename, sha256=[my laptop sha-256 key], atk=false, ver=240213038.true (go/gsrlt)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(29377):     at m.crb.s(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@240213038@24.02.13 (190400-0):21)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(29377):     at m.crb.get(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@240213038@24.02.13 (190400-0):5)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(29377):     at m.csl.g(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@240213038@24.02.13 (190400-0):9)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(29377):     at m.cal.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@240213038@24.02.13 (190400-0):1)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(29377):     at m.cat.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@240213038@24.02.13 (190400-0):5)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(29377):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:487)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(29377):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(29377):     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:307)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(29377):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(29377):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(29377):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(29377): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: GoogleCertificatesRslt: not allowed: pkg=com.example.packagename, sha256=[my laptop sha-256 key], atk=false, ver=240213038.true (go/gsrlt)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(29377):     at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3057)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(29377):     at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:3041)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(29377):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:3024)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(29377):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2966)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(29377):     at m.ahs.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@240213038@24.02.13 (190400-0):11)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(29377):     at m.bfg.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@240213038@24.02.13 (190400-0):39)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(29377):     at m.atl.e(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@240213038@24.02.13 (190400-0):11)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(29377):     at m.aui.u(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@240213038@24.02.13 (190400-0):10)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(29377):     at m.aui.v(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@240213038@24.02.13 (190400-0):22)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(29377):     at m.aui.e(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@240213038@24.02.13 (190400-0):16)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(29377):     at m.aum.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@240213038@24.02.13 (190400-0):664)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(29377):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(29377):     at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(29377):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
W/MobStoreFlagStore(29377):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

Comment: Is this in live or in test mode? if it's in live did you submit your app to Google to get permission to use Google Pay? https://stripe.com/docs/google-pay?platform=react-native#going-live-react-native

Comment: My ap  is in test  mode

Comment: @karllekko bro you know  how to  resolve  this in  test mode??